# How to Find the PNP Device Id in File System Driver for windows

Tags: c, windows, filesystems, kernel, driver

I have created a File system driver to allow or block the external storage devices in windows. For allowing a particular device I need to find out the PNP device id. Is there is any possible way to find the PNP id device?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [IRP_MN_QUERY_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/irp-mn-query-id), and using the BusQueryDeviceID to get the identificator into a buffer.

You can also use  IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY to get some data that is usually part of the id, like the vendor and productid.

Please note that not all hardware is guaranteed (in fact, most don't) to have unique identifiers.